# Jquery to create string from input data attributes

Tags: jquery

I am creating a search form that grabs the data attributes from form inputs, creates an array and then converts it to a string to send to an API search call.

My HTML is:

```
        <input data-group="filters" data-param="month">
        <input data-group="filters" data-param="year">            
        <input data-group="filters" data-param="name">
        <button data-input="filters" id="search">Search</button>
```

My JS is:

```
 $('#search').on('click', function () {    
        var input_group = $(this).data('input');
        var inputs = $('input[data-group="' + input_group + '"]');
        var values = [];        
        $(inputs).each(function () {
            values.push($(this).data("param"));
            values.push($(this).val());     
        });    
        str = values.join([separator = '&']);
        str = 'http://www.example.com/search/?' + str;
    });
});
```

`str` currently reads:

```
http://www.example.com/search/month&January&year&2015&name&Jane
```

but what I want is:

```
http://www.example.com/search/?month=January&year=2015&name=Jane
```

How do i insert an `=` between `month` and `January` and then follow it up with `&` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you cannot use the inputs `name` attributes? If so, you could simply use jQuery's [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

If you need to go ahead with what you have right now, the reason you are seeing this behavior is because you're adding both the name and the value to the same array:

```
values.push($(this).data("param"));
values.push($(this).val());
```

... and subsequently joining them with `&` as the delimiter.

You need to add the `=` where you are adding the items:

```
values.push(
   $(this).data("param") + "=" + $(this).val()
);
```

Comment: Marked Answered for serialize suggestion - which I will be using. And for answering with what I have right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#search').on('click', function () {    
        var input_group = $(this).data('input');
        var inputs = $('input[data-group="' + input_group + '"]');
        var values = [];        
        $(inputs).each(function () {
            // Differences start
            var full_parameter = values.push($(this).data("param")); 
            full_parameter += '=';
            full_parameter += $(this).val();

            values.push(full_parameter); 
            // Differences end    
        });    
        str = values.join([separator = '&']);
        str = 'http://www.mysite.com.au/search/?' + str;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using

```
$(inputs).each(function () {
    values.push($(this).data("param") + "=" + $(this).val());
});
```

instead of

```
$(inputs).each(function () {
    values.push($(this).data("param"));
    values.push($(this).val());     
});
```